# How to make gcc complain about comparison of char with 256

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I found the following code on [codegolf.stackexchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24639/36005) to print a code table for ASCII characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        printf("%3d 0x%2x: %c\n", i, i, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since `char`s store single bytes in them, they are always `< 256` and the loop never terminates. I would like to detect this upon compilation.

Nicely, `clang` gives the following warning:

```
a.c:5:18: warning: comparison of constant 256 with expression of type 'char' is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
           ~ ^ ~~~
```

However, neither `gcc` nor `gcc -Wall` give any warning of any sort. Is there any set of command line options I can give to turn on this kind of warnings? Or is it not possible in gcc?

Comment: 1. `char` may be signed, in which case `CHAR_MAX` may be `127`. 2. `CHAR_BIT` may be bigger than 8, in which case `CHAR_MAX` may be bigger than `256`.

Comment: Does `gcc -Wall` give an error/warning if you change 256 to 257?  The compiler might internally rewrite the comparison to <= 255 and realize no warning is needed.

Comment: That's strange, cause my gcc 3.4.4 with `-Wall` always gave me warnings about always-true and always-false comparisons.
You can also try `-Wpedantic`, though I don't think it should be needed.

Comment: Add `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? [GCC 5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) appeared in mid july 2015.

Comment: Side note: This highlights the troubles in C of using a type narrower than `int/unsigned` for computation.  Code could/should have been `int/unsigned i;`.

Comment: @chux: I agree for modern CPUs with 16 or 32 bit. However, for smaller systems (8 bit and even some 16 bit architectures), this is sometimes not an option and smaller types very well hint the compiler to optimize (the standard allows to perform operations with smaller size if the result will not change).

Comment: @Olaf Agree using a narrow than `int` type` is good hint for a narrow CPU for optimization.  Yet specifying that narrow type could well limit optimization on a wider CPU when code is ported.  Maybe that is what `int_fast8_t` is for?

Comment: @chux: You are right - in theory. In practice, any port to a different (possibly wider register) MCU will require most of the code to be re-written anyway (peripherals, use of RT-OS, clean structure not possible on small arch, etc. Even for a larger CPU this must times is only true for higher layers. Programming an 8-bitter or even 16 bitter is much different from ARM Cortex-M, e.g., not to talk about Full-size OS based. (and for existing code, I'm already very happy to see `uint8_t` & friends. Most engineers still use their own creatures - or even the standard types:-(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Wtype-limits` (or `-Wextra`) should trigger this warning

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`. The first includes a warning for your actual probem, but the latter will warn about many other related problems.

But beware: `-Wconversion` will also warn about many other potential problems if your code is not well-written (signed/unsigned, etc). Best is to compile, see the warnings and carefully verify the listed lines, possibly adding casts (after thinking thrice if the code is correct!).

Comment: `-Wextra` gives a warning but `-Wconversion` does not, for this specific case.

Comment: @JayBosamiya: "... The first includes a warning for your actual probem, but ..." I think that states it quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the posted code with gcc, on ubuntu 14.04 linux using:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
```

and the compiler output this warning:

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
```

Just one more reason to always enable all the warnings when compiling